# API call in Response and another response types

Tags: ibm-cloud, watson-conversation

How can I call API url (`Fulfillment` or `Webhook` as named by API.AI) from Watson conversation API Response.

I don't need to enter the full list of expected responses from the Response section.

I need to call an API with the understood JSON object to handle the response from the backend (fetch DB for example) and return the expected JSON to the user (requester).

Any advice?!

Comment: You need to code in the back-end(if you are using the nodejs application) and override the if condition based on your intent name

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand your question, you cannot program within the Conversation service tooling to call out to other services etc, as part of a response or message. 
These are the types of actions that the middleware or service layer part of your application should handle. Not to be recommended but you could program the client element of your application to process additional api calls. 
You will find both on this forum, and in the IBM docs examples of the use of whats called "action" json elements that can be added to your conversation response payload. Thus along with the response output text ( or in place ) you add an "action" json element to the output and context json object that includes instructions to your middleware or client part of your application. i.e. 
"output" : { "Text" : "Hi there" }, 
"action" " { "api_url" : "http://bluemixservice.ibm.com", "Task" : "insert", "data" : "User asked for an alarm at 5pm" }, 
"context" : { "conversation_id" : "asdada" } 

Hope this helps.